# fix or workaround: "Terminal is not fully functional"

Tags: shell, terminal-emacs, eshell, ssh

What can I do about this issue? I'm using

psql, inside a ssh tunnel to ubuntu, inside a `M-x shell`, inside a `emacsclient -nw`

[image]

Comment: There's `eshell` as well, have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104325/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-eshell-and-term-in-emacs

Comment: And http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_shell_vs_term_vs_ansi-term_vs_eshell.html

Comment: @A.Blizzard eshell is not a terminal emulator either, it will produce the same, or similar, warnings as shell-mode

Comment: Eshell indeed _is_ a terminal emulator, fully written in LISP, what makes it a breeze to use Emacs commands like find-file or find-file-other-window to open files from the terminal. **The above comment is wrong.**

Comment: @solr `eshell` is not a **fully functional** terminal I meant to say. It doesn't support visual commands such as the one in this question.

Comment: Eshell is not a terminal emulator.  It's a shell (obviously; it's right there in the name).  Any terminal-like functionality provided by eshell is going to be rudimentary and line-oriented -- there's a very good reason that eshell hands off to an *actual* terminal emulator (`term.el`) for running commands which need anything more than a dumb terminal.  It's even right there in its own manual at `(eshell)Input/Output`: "...since the Eshell buffer is not a terminal emulator."

Comment: @lawlist I don't understand what more you want for a 'canonical' answer. The message `WARNING: ...` is not generated by Emacs, it shows up anytime a program requires a fully functional terminal to display output, and is being run in a terminal/shell that doesn't support that. `M-x shell` and `eshell` don't support the required features. There are terminal emulators in Emacs that do, i.e., `ansi-term`.

Comment: @Tyler -- Thank you for having another look at this thread.  I was hoping for a setting to bypass the warning and let me proceed without pressing the return key; e.g., setting the `process-connection-type` to nil or something like that to create a workaround.  I really like using `eshell`, and have been forced to use `term` and `ansi-term` for the past few days ....  Or something like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23388276/2112489

Answer (score 14):

## Quick answer

That's not an issue, it's a statement of fact. `M-x shell` isn't a fully functional terminal - it simply can't do what you want it to do. If you want a full terminal emulator in emacs, you have to use `M-x ansi-term` instead.

## Explanation

This isn't an Emacs issue per se, but a consequence of how different kinds of terminals process input, and especially output. All terminals support printing raw text, and accept lines of input ending with a return (enter key).

Some terminals also support escape sequences (which allow for coloured text), clearing lines, and controlling cursor position. Xterm is an example of this, and using these features you can create a complex interface like the Mutt mail program, or formatting and scrolling support as found in the terminal Man page viewer.

Terminals without these features are called `dumb terminals`. Dumb terminals can only print single color text to the screen, and can't back up or overwrite lines, as is necessary for an interactive display like Mutt provides, or Man uses to scroll up and down through a manual.

When a program that requires these features is started, it usually checks to see if the terminal supports them. One way to do this is to check the value of the environmental variable `TERM`. If the value of that variable is `dumb`, the program knows it can't rely on all the features it expects, and will warn the user with the message reported here.

You can still use a program that requires a fully functional terminal in a dumb terminal. There's no guarantee it will function properly, or at all. That's why you get the warning. If you really want to use such programs in a dumb terminal, without the warning, you could manually set the value of `TERM` to `xterm`, i.e.,

```bash
export TERM=xterm
```

You will no longer get the warning message, and you won't have to press `enter` before you can see the program output. But after that, the program will still behave strangely, because you have tricked it into thinking it can use features that aren't there.

That might work for simple cases. It would not work at all for Mutt.

In the Emacs context, `M-x shell` is a dumb terminal, built from the `comint` library. It is Emacs, so it would be possible in theory to extend it to fully support all the features of a fully-functional shell. I expect that is non-trivial. In practice, `ansi-term` already exists to fulfill this function.

## Eshell

`eshell` is a different kind of entity, being a terminal and shell written completely in elisp, and making it a special case that I won't get into here. I will note that the people who developed `Eshell` anticipate that users will want to use programs that require fully-functional shell features from within Eshell. They provide facilities to integrate `ansi-term` with `eshell`, with a bit of [configuration (Eshell manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Input_002fOutput.html#Input_002fOutput):

> If you try to run programs from within Eshell that are not line-oriented, such as programs that use ncurses, you will just get garbage output, since the Eshell buffer is not a terminal emulator. Eshell solves this problem by running such programs in Emacs’s terminal emulator.
> Programs that need a terminal to display output properly are referred
> to in this manual as “visual commands,” because they are not simply
> line-oriented.  You must tell Eshell which commands are visual, by
> adding them to ‘eshell-visual-commands’; for commands that are visual
> for only certain *sub*-commands – e.g., ‘git log’ but not ‘git status’ –
> use ‘eshell-visual-subcommands’; and for commands that are visual only
> when passed certain options, use ‘eshell-visual-options’.

This should address most use cases. Note that the recommended solution of the `eshell` developers is not to change `eshell`, but to automatically switch to `ansi-term` when `eshell` is incapable of providing the necessary features. Which brings us back to the short answer above: use `ansi-term` when you need a fully-functional terminal.

## What about `M-x shell`?

Emacs' `shell` doesn't have built-in support for visual commands like `eshell` does. You can add support yourself with relatively little effort. For example, the command line program `man` doesn't work properly in a dumb terminal, but there is an Emacs mode for it. You can call it directly from `M-x shell` by including the following function in your `.emacs.d/init_bash.sh` file:

```bash
function man() {
    emacsclient -e "(man \"$@\")"
}
```

This requires that you are running emacs in daemon/server mode. If you are, using the `man` command from the Emacs shell will pass the argument to the elisp function `man`, opening the file in a buffer and displaying it properly.

You could use the same principle to replace programs with functions that do the appropriate thing for other programs. For instance, creating a function named `mutt` that opens and `ansi-term` buffer and runs the command `mutt` in it.

Comment: I digress with this answer and consequently voted it down: when your workflow is interrupted like with this waning message, where you need to press an extra key to move forwards, then it turns into an annoying issue.

Comment: @solr Yes, it is annoying to use a terminal that isn't fully functional when you need a fully functional terminal. That's why you should use the fully functional `ansi-term` instead of limited functions of `shell` in this situation. What exactly are you disagreeing with?

Comment: Thank you @Tyler for the more detailed explanation and the suggested workarounds.  I only had enough steam left in the engine this evening to try out the answer of `db48x`, which worked so I went ahead and gave that forum participant the bonus points.  I will also try your suggested workarounds in the next day or so.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about whether Emacs is a "fully-functional" terminal or not and you just want it to work without making you press enter, then run the psql command `\pset pager off`. This will make psql skip running a pager program and just dump all the output at once. You can then scroll through the output using the Emacs scrollbar or scrolling commands. The pager that it runs is typically `less`, which is what prints this message. You could also use `\pset pager more` to run `more` as the pager instead. `more` doesn't need many terminal capabilities and so it doesn't bother to print this message.

You could also arrange for the `PAGER` environment variable to be unset or to have a different value such as `more`.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do about this issue? I'm using
> `psql`, inside a `ssh` tunnel to ubuntu, inside a `M-x shell`, inside a `emacsclient -nw`

In short, "don't do that".

Emacs has excellent comint-based support for `psql` via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sql-postgres`, and the `sql-interactive-mode` buffer created by that can interact with `sql-mode` buffers so that you can write queries in the latter and send them to the former.  In Emacs I wouldn't want to be running `psql` any other way.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding the following line to my`~/.bashrc` file (note the whitespace around the square brackets matters)

```sh
[ "$TERM" = "dumb" ] && export PAGER=cat
```

Without this change, my `PAGER` environment variable was set to `less -R`, which is what gives the warning (i.e. try running `echo foo | less -R`).  The nice thing about this fix is it should only apply to shells that need it because it only sets `PAGER` when `TERM=dumb`.

Answer (score 0):

`export TERM=eterm ;`  Inside your `M-x shell`

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you explain your post in more detail to make it a complete answer?